# Information about component quality in general and quality of memory IS25LP128-JBL

Tags: memory, flash-memories

Most of us are faced with component quality especially when producing product in higher quantities. What is he right place to find information about component quality in general? 
Currently we faced with problem of `IS25LP128-JBL` memory. Sometimes it does not hold memory after several read/write cycles. We are getting feedback from 1000 products. In previous product version memory `AT25DF641` is working like a charm. Does anybody has problems with `IS25LP128-JBL` too?

Comment: Are you sure it's a component quality issue and not a handling or processing issue? Was anything changed in the handling/processing to accommodate the part?  And did you did you buy the parts from the same (reputable) distributor as you did for your original part?

Comment: The people to ask about this are the ISSI applications engineers. If any of us did have information about quality issues with this part, it would be proprietary information of our employers. (I guess a self-employed person might choose to share what they know, but that's not many of us)

Comment: I'm sure it is component quality issue. Most of components work fine. We did double check of handling/processing issues. And we buy this part from reputable distributor

Comment: We have experience of asking producers regarding quality issues is always respond with silence. But why sharing information about component quality is prohibited in your company? It is problem of component, not product which is designed in your company.